# MS Access Boolean Field and Default (True) Value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

I am trying - Using the following queries - to add a new Boolean field with a TRUE default value in MS Access 2007 datbase, but it doesn't work. As it always set the default value FALSE.

```
ALTER TABLE Banks ADD COLUMN _Active BIT -1
ALTER TABLE Banks ADD COLUMN _Active YESNO -1
ALTER TABLE Banks ADD COLUMN _Active LOGICAL -1
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute your DDL statement from `CurrentProject.Connection`.  This version worked for me in Access 2010:

```vb
strSql = "ALTER TABLE Banks ADD COLUMN _Active YESNO DEFAULT True"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Afterward, if you want to set a Format (such as True/False or Yes/No) or set the Display Control to checkbox, you'll need to use VBA to adjust the field's properties.  Those can't be done with Access DDL.

Comment: It worked when I use the same query via a Delphi application, thank you @HansUp

Answer (score 1):

Include the `DEFAULT` keyword after the data type.  You should be able to use either of the ones that you tried (`BIT`, `LOGICAL`, or  `YESNO`)

```
ALTER TABLE Banks ADD COLUMN _Active BIT DEFAULT -1
```

Comment: When I use `DEFAULT`, it gives a syntax error message and when I remove `DEFAULT` it works but with `FALSE` value